# sound problem / kernel signature

Tags: asus, soundcard, signature

I have an asus zenbook ux430unr, and I would like to use ubuntu on it.
I installed ubuntu 20.04 and unfortunately the sound card is unsupported on its kernel version (5.4.0-37-generic).
So I installed a newer kernel using ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -i, it was updated to 5.7.5.
Now I am facing a new problem, which is signing the kernel, on boot, it tells me "invalid signature, please load the kernel first".
The good news is, if I disbale secure boot everything works flawlessly and the sound works just fine, but I don't want to disable secure boot since I am dual booting and then windows wouldn't boot up.
Can someone help me with my problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why Windows doesn't boot wit Secure Boot disabed? It should boot. Maybe some setting is needed there. There is no Ubuntu signed 5.7 kernel yet.

Comment: I think it is because of bitlocker
isn't there a way to sign it myself?